# What is the powerset of an ordered pair?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the definition of an identity related to cartesian products, so naturally there are some ordered pairs. My prof did a crummy job on definitions though, and the text isn't great either, so:

If I have:

A = 1, 2

B = 3, 4

AxB = (1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)

What would be the powerset?
Would that be (partial example):
{(1,3),(1,4)} or could you separate these elements so you'd have items like 
{1}, {4}, {(1,3), (1,4)} as part of the powerset?

Comment: Do you mean the powerset of the Cartesian product $A\times B$?

Comment: Your first partial example is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $A \times B = \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$. This has 4 elements.

This means its powerset will have $16 = 2^4$ elements and these are sets of pairs as in your first example. So $\{(1,3),(1,4)\}$ is one of them, the set $\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$ itself is also in the powerset, as is the emptyset $\emptyset$. Also singleton sets like $\{(1,3)\}$ (and three more), and sets of three elements like $\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)\}$ etc.

In forming a powerset we just consider all elements of the set, and either put them in a subset or not. It does not matter if the elements of the set we start with are themselves pairs (like here), or are themselves sets, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is that you didnt specify what the original set is. As another user mentioned, if your set is $A\times B$, then that has $4$ elements and its powerset contains $2^4$.

If your original set is $\{1,2,3,4\}$, then the powerset also happens to have $2^4$ elements, but these are different from the powerset in the first example.

Finally, the example you offered would be the powerset of $A\cup B\cup A\times B$. I don't really see why you would ever be interested in that, though, especially since you would be mixing single elements with ordered pairs.